# Building with Ant

Tags: android

I've installed Ant. From an existing Eclipse project I am able to generate the build.xml file from the command line using ant -update project. When I now try ant release I get this error: `build.xml:65: java.lang.NullPointerException.`

This project builds fine under Eclipse. I have no idea where to even begin to figure this out. I wouldn't bother with this except that I need to use ProGuard later on (which I have not done yet). Any ideas?

Comment: What's on line 65 of build.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

*I was using a library that did not have a `libs` folder.*

Resolution process is as follows:

1. Creating the `libs` folder.
2. Putting an empty `.nodelete` file in it.

Then it all worked for me. I found this obscure fix on another post somewhere. I would have never figured it out.